# Book title with a harsh alien world and buoyant balloon-like beings

Tags: story-identification, aliens, planets

I specifically remember that those **buoyant** explosive gas filled **balloons were an annoyance** for flying ships. This is mentioned several times in the book.
At the end they seemed to play a very important role in the plot.
I also remember ground based predators named **Dashers**, other named **Swifters** and the like.
I read it in the '90s, it but could be older.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it [The Jesus Incident](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jesus_Incident)? By Frank Herbert and Bill Ransom

This piece from a [Google Good reads search](https://books.google.ie/books?id=D37J_yLGukIC&pg=PT193&lpg=PT193&dq=the%20jesus%20incident%20dasher&source=bl&ots=abrS1sU6OW&sig=_wfUmXJ2NjoKzcEPNozgbdM1SNE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=5PuTVfCRO9GXygSOwKCQAw&ved=0CCUQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=the%20jesus%20incident%20dasher&f=false) confirms that there were predators called dashers.

> Until she saw him sprint across the east plain, a Hooded Dasher close
>   behind, Legata did not know Thomas was at the Redoubt . . . Thomas
>   swerved abruptly to the left, made a desperate leap off a dangerously
>   high rock onto the sand at the high tide mark. The Dasher leaped after
>   him, misjudged and landed in a patch of dead kelp washed up by the
>   surf. It immediately began gulping rags of kelp dropping from a high
>   rock, running as it landed.

Comment: The title doesn't sound right to my ears. I'll take a look and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, but It seems this is not the book I'm looking for. I didn't see any mention of buoyant ballons in it. Thanks anyway.

Comment: "The Jesus Incident" is the novel you are looking for.  The Balloon creatures are called hylighters.  From http://www.theverge.com/2012/9/9/3303946/classics-the-jesus-incident-frank-herbert-bill-ransom, "The majority of events take place on Pandora, a planet of extremes populated by unique creatures like the peaceful, orange, jellyfish-like hylighters that float in the sky, and a sentient kelp that communicates by flashing multicolored lights."

Comment: The balloon animals as also know in the book as "floaters", they have poisonous/acidic tendrils that can trail along the ground.

Comment: Yep, they were indeed orange and had tendrils. I'm seeing too many coincidences for it to be the wrong book. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Not much to go on, but how about "[The Ragged Astronauts](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1346)" or one of its sequels by Bob Shaw?  The book features flying ships and there are balloon animals ("ptertha") that contain a toxin that is a major issue when the balloons zoom up to you and pop.  The ptertha do indeed become a major plot point.

The books are really good btw, I highly recommend them.

Comment: Now that you mention it, I think the ballons chased the passing by ships.